# I3 wm PageUp and PageDown remap names in config file are Prior and Next

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, i3-window-manager, configuration-managment

How can I bind PageUp and PageDown key in i3 configuration file ? using PageUp and PageDown does not work.

Comment: I let this information here as I did not succeed in googling this information clearly and had to guess.

Answer (score 2):

When I want to map PageUp and PageDown key in my i3 config file I have to use terms Prior (PageUp) and Next (PageDown), so I am able to remap keys like this for exemple on my laptop :

`bindsym --release $mod+Prior exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers Home`

`bindsym --release $mod+Next exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers End`

Note: the remap key trick requires to install xdotool program.

Answer (score 0):

On a lenovo laptop pageup and pagedown are too close to the arrows so I accidentally type them when I don't intend to.

I use the following:

```
bindsym Prior nop
bindsym Next nop
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).